# Is it an SQL SERVER bug?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, stored-functions

I cant seem to figure out what is going on with this SQL scalar function.  I am wondering if this is some kind of bug that I've fallen upon because the select statement is returning NULL in the function while it works perfectly well outside the function or when the DESC clause is omitted.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[getInvoiceNumbers]
(

@vatable bit

)
RETURNS nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @latestNonVATInvNumber nvarchar(20), 
        @latestVATInvNumber nvarchar(20), @invoiceNumber nvarchar(20)

if @vatable = 'true'
    begin    
        select TOP 1 @latestVATInvNumber = invoiceNumber from dbo.Invoices where vatable = 'true' ORDER BY invoiceID desc 

        /* remove 'B' from invoice number and convert to int from string */

        set @latestVATInvNumber = cast(substring(@latestVATInvNumber,2,len(@latestVATInvNumber)) as int) + 1

        /* Add 'B' to receipt number with leading zeros so that it is 7 digits including 'B' */

        set @latestVATInvNumber  = 'B' + RIGHT('000000'+ CAST(@latestVATInvNumber AS VARCHAR(6)),6)

        set @invoiceNumber = @latestVATInvNumber
    end
else
    begin

        select TOP 1 @latestNonVATInvNumber = invoiceNumber from dbo.Invoices where vatable = (select cast ('False' as bit)) ORDER BY invoiceID desc


        /* Invoice Number is numeric (non VAT) hence only incrementing it by 1 */

        set @latestNonVATInvNumber = cast(cast(@latestNonVATInvNumber as int) + 1 as nvarchar(10))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

        set @invoiceNumber = @latestNonVATInvNumber
    end

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @invoiceNumber 

END
```

The part that is giving `NULL` is this piece of code:

```
select TOP 1 @latestNonVATInvNumber = invoiceNumber from dbo.Invoices where vatable = (select cast ('False' as bit)) ORDER BY invoiceID desc
```

and

```
 select TOP 1 @latestVATInvNumber = invoiceNumber from dbo.Invoices where vatable = 'true' ORDER BY invoiceID desc
```

If I remove the 'DESC' then it gives me the result from database or even if 'ASC' is inserted but as is, the statement is returning `NULL` when there is a record for vatable = 'false' in the table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the data type of the `vatable` column?

Comment: Data type of 'vatable' column is BIT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Suggestion One (incorrect):

The first time you query the table, you use the following filter:

`where vatable = 'true'`

The second time you query it, you use the following:

`(select cast ('False' as bit))`

Change them to match each other by removing the CAST and using `where vatable = 'false'`.

### Suggestion Two (Answer):

Add `AND InvoiceNumber IS NOT NULL` to your condition

Comment: Tried both and did not work, that is why I was trying the CAST thinking whether the BIT column was messing up in the query.  Both queries work perfectly well when run separately or when run on their own.

Comment: Try adding `AND InvoiceNumber IS NOT NULL` to your condition and check if / how many rows are returned

Comment: AHiggins you got it there mate, thanks.  Adding this clause did the trick. Can you explain why because the InvoiceNumber column cannot contain NULL and cannot be empty?

Comment: select TOP 1 @latestVATInvNumber = invoiceNumber from dbo.Invoices 
   where vatable = 'true' AND invoiceNumber IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY invoiceID desc

Comment: So you're saying the InvoiceNumber column is defined as not containing a NULL value? `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Invoices WHERE InvoiceNumber IS NULL` returns a zero?

Comment: Correct.  I just ran your SELECT and it returned 0.  The column allows NULL at the moment because of testing going on but in production cannot contain NULL.  And for the moment, the table does not contain NULL for InvoiceNumber which is the twist and my initial SELECT works perfectly when run separately but NOT in the function.

Answer (score 1):

With you using TOP 1 if you are returning more than 1 row then changing the order of the results returned could change the output given back to your @latestNonVATInvNumber variable.

What I would suggest is testing the top 1 part and try to select COUNT(*) to see how many rows are returned.

e.g.

```
select COUNT(*) from dbo.Invoices where vatable = (select cast ('False' as bit)) ORDER BY invoiceID desc
```

Then you could test what data is returned with something like

```
select * from dbo.Invoices where vatable = (select cast ('False' as bit)) ORDER BY invoiceID desc
```

Maybe then it will become clearer why a NULL is appearing.

Comment: As far as I know, TOP 1 usually returns only 1 row.  But tried your suggestion by modifying the select to this "select COUNT(*) from dbo.Invoices where vatable = (select cast ('False' as bit)) GROUP BY invoiceID".  As expected, count(*) returns only 1 row.